# Google Play Achievements Messed Up

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I need Some help. I have set up my google play achievements something like this. consider this are the list of my achievemnts in my game in dev console. the ordering in sample one is the default ordering i want

fig 1

```
 1. test1
 2. test2
 3. test3
 4. test4
 5. test5_hidden
 6. test6
 7. test7
 8. test8
```

the problem is everytime i show achievements in my app. the ordering is messed up like this. Do you know how to git rid of this>?

```
1. test4
2. test3
3. test2
4. test1
5. test6
6. test7
7. test8
8. test5_hidden
```

I think [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements) is just a crap

**List order is the order in which the achievement appears when a player views the achievements associated with your game. This can be in any order that you like.**

**This can be in any order that you like** -oh really?

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that the ordering is messed up when you display achievements with the Google default UI. Well, you can't. I ended making my own UI for that.

(by the way, the order is not "messed up", it's order by the last interaction the user got with the achievement, or by the last unlocked achievement. Don't remember exactly but there's a logic behind.)

Comment: I see. I though it should be in order, Thanks btw

Comment: Have you tried altering this - http://imgur.com/nK1BM9P

Comment: @Clay, yup. still no use.